# Contents of plist file to a NSString

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4

Is there a way I can read the contents of plist file and put it into a string. e.g my plist file contains this data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>a.infoKey</key>
    <array>
        <string>a</string>
        <string>a</string>
        <string>a</string>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>a.titleKey</key>
    <string>a</string>
    <key>r.infoKey</key>
    <array>
        <string>r</string>
        <string>r</string>
        <string>r</string>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>r.titleKey</key>
    <string>r</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to put the contents of the whole file with all the text starting from `<?xml ... </plist>` into ONE NSString or NSMutableString. Can it be done?

Comment: Try NSString's `initWithContentsOfFile:` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *myPlistContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```